# I don't understand why/how one of these methods is faster than the others

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I wanted to test the difference in time between implementations of some simple code. I decided to count how many values out of a random sample of 10,000,000 numbers is greater than 0.5. The random sample is grabbed uniformly from the range [0.0, 1.0).

Here is my code:

```
from numpy.random import random_sample; import time; 
n = 10000000;

t1 = time.clock();

t = 0;
z = random_sample(n);
for x in z:
    if x > 0.5: t += 1;
print t;

t2 = time.clock();

t = 0;
for _ in xrange(n):
    if random_sample() > 0.5: t += 1;
print t;

t3 = time.clock();

t = (random_sample(n) > 0.5).sum();
print t;

t4 = time.clock();

print t2-t1; print t3-t2; print t4-t3;
```

This is the output:

```
4999445
4999511
5001498
7.0348236652
1.75569394301
0.202538106332
```

---

I get that the first implementation sucks because creating a massive array and then counting it element-wise is a bad idea, so I thought that the second implementation would be the most efficient.

But how is the third implementation 10 times faster than the second method? Doesn't the third method also create a massive array in the form of `random_sample(n)` and then go through it checking values against 0.5?

How is this third method different from the first method and why is it ~35 times faster than the first method?

---

EDIT: @merlin2011 suggested that Method 3 probably doesn't create the full array in memory. So, to test that theory I tried the following:

```
z = random_sample(n);
t = (z > 0.5).sum();
print t;
```

which runs in a time of `0.197948451549` which is practically identical to Method 3. So, this is probably not a factor.

Comment: I updated it based on your results. I will run some tests of my own as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Method 1 generates a full list in memory before using it. This is slow because the memory has to be allocated and then accessed, probably missing the cache multiple times.
2. Method 2 uses an generator, which never creates the list in memory but instead generates each element on demand.
3. Method 3 is probably faster because `sum()` is implemented as a loop in `C` but I am not 100% sure. My guess is that this is faster for the same reason that Matlab vectorization is faster than `for` loops in Matlab.

**Update**: Separating out each of three steps, I observe that method 3 is still equally fast, so I have to agree with utdemir that each individual operator is executing instructions closer to machine code.

```
z = random_sample(n)
z2 = z > 0.5
t = z2.sum();
```

In each of the first two methods, you are invoking Python's standard functionality to do a loop, and this is much slower than a C-level loop that is baked into the implementation.

Comment: I decided to test that theory, and it seems that creating the full array in memory doesn't make a difference. (See my Edit to original post).

So, it seems that Method 3 does actually create the entire array and then checks all the elements just like Method 1.

Comment: Thanks! This helps. I know what I am looking for now.

Comment: @NikhilMahajan, You are welcome. This is an interesting discussion.

Comment: I wonder how close `>` in python is to the compare and jump if greater than functions in assembly.

Comment: @NikhilMahajan, Pure speculation, but I would say `>` on a single element is probably pretty close to optimal, while the interpreted loop is slow. If you run a benchmark and prove me wrong, please add a comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK

- Function calls are heavy, on method two, you're calling `random_sample()` 10000000 times, but on third method, you just call it once.
- Numpy's `>` and `.sum` are optimized to their last bits in C, also most probably using SIMD instructions to avoid loops.

So,

On method 2, you are comparing and looping using Python; but on method 3, you're much closer to the processor and using optimized instructions to compare and sum.